# unable to listen to voice mails on iPhone right away - greyed out

Tags: iphone

My wife and I have iPhone 6 pluses with latest IOS software. Phones are Verizon service. She gets voice mails right away but is not able to listen to them right away. The play button is greyed out. Has anyone else seen this and is there a solution or something we can check?

Comment: When you say 'right away' do you mean she can't listen to them immediately or do you mean she can't listen to them ever?  The messages have to download from Verizon's servers so there's a delay depending on your network connection.

Comment: @fsb- they are greyed out right away and eventually she can listen to them like maybe a day later. When I get voice mails they are available right away. She says not all of them are delayed